# adding 2nd catalog for linked server to DB2

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, db2, linked-server, db2-luw

I am unable to figure out how to add multiple catalogs for a DB2 linked server.

I have an initial Linked server setup and working properly, but I am struggling to figure out how to add multiple databases from the DB2 instance (version 11.1), using below:

> Microsoft SQL Server 2014 (SP2) (KB3171021) - 12.0.5000.0 (X64)   Jun 17 2016 19:14:09   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.3  (Build 9600: ) (Hypervisor) .

Comment: My APP team is restricting me to only one linked server (for automation) per server.  Hence my attempt to create additional catalogs

Answer (score 1):

From my experience there can be just 1 catalog per 1 linked server

You will need to create separate linked servers for each database on remote server (DB2) that you want to be available for querying on your "local" server (SQL Server)